# Using PrimeFaces editor in a TabView with dynamic set to false

Tags: jsf, primefaces, editor, tabview

It seems that adding a p:editor to a TabView with dynamic="false" fails to initialize the editor unless its in the first tab. I tried adding

```
onTabShow="handleTabShow(tab)"

function handleTabShow(tab) {
    if (tab.index() === 7) {
        editorWidgetVar.init();
    }
}
```

to the tabView, but this fails to initialize the editor. I have the same problem with onTabChange. Does anyone know how to get a primefaces editor to load in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was not adding the editorWidgetVar.cfg as a parameter to the init() function. If I do this it works...seems weird that there isnt a simpler, less hacky way to get this editor to display...